# How to use gcc dynamic linker

Tags: ubuntu, c, gcc, shared-library, ld

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    return printf("helloworld %d",a);
}
```

lib.c:

```
int a=0;
```

`test.c` is using the variable `a` from `lib.c`. I turned it into the shared library `lib.so`.

```
gcc testbench.c -o test -l lib.so
```

throws an error :

`‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

This is unexpected, since it was declared in `lib.c`.

Comment: Note the return value of `printf`, is not compatible with the return value of main. (I did not say type, the type is compatible).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor What problem do you see here? both functions have an `int` as return type and both have the same permitted range.

Comment: The *type* is compatible, the *meaning* is not.

Comment: You need to have `extern int a;` in `testbench.c`. Note that there are platforms like `macOS` that use a stone age linker that does not support to link against variables inside shared libraries but all platforms that are based on `SunOS` dynamic linker code will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to communicate the compiler that `a` exists externally to the source file.  To do that, declare it as `extern`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a;

int main(void)
{
    printf("helloworld %d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with **dynamic**, the same problem will happen with static linking.

The problem is that you have not declared it. You have however defined it.
You need to declare it with `extern int a;`, before it is used.

You should do this in a file named `lib.h` (same name as the compilation unit, and include it from `lib.c` (to verify it), and from `main.c` to use it.

## main.c

```
#include "lib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("helloworld %d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

## lib.h

```
extern int a;
```

## lib.c

```
#include "lib.h"
/*other includes that we need, after including own .h*/
/*so we can catch missing dependencies*/
int a=0;
```